# Using API to post data into Kepware OPC Server

Tags: raspberry-pi, modbus, opc

I'm using Raspberry Pi to make an API Post call to an OPC Server. It would have to use Modbus Protocol to push in the data, but the step I'm struggling with is posting a synthetic data into the Server to check if it works before going into details.

Anyone have any insight on how I can do this?

Comment: You seem to be confused. Are you trying to communicate with Kepware via OPC-UA or via Modbus? Have you tried using an OPC-UA client library?

Comment: I'm trying to put Raspberry Pi between the PLC and OPC Server to intercept data.

Answer (score 0):

The PLC and OPC(UA) Server can communicate each other, you don't need to do anything.

Usually we use Raspberry Pi to subscribe and read data from OPC UA Server, then pack it and post to our server. there's a set of APIs. The server will store data into Database.
So here is the flow:

PLC -> OPC(UA) Server -> Raspberry Pi(Node-Red, OPC UA Client) -> RESTful APIs -> Database

Then we can query it from some web application.

When the Node-Red flow starting, it will get a tag list from API, then store it into a local MySQL database in case the network is down. then start to subscribe or read something. Data will also have a local copy and then send to remote.